# Why would I want to use Salesforce API's ? for example REST API?

Tags: rest-api, api

Could you please give me examples for why Salesforce customers would want to use these API's? Like what kind of applications? 
These API's are not intended to be used from Apex classes right?

Thanks !

Comment: check these articles [Salesforce APIs – What They Are & When to Use Them](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2011/10/salesforce-apis-what-they-are-when-to-use-them.html) and [Which API Should I Use?](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm)

Comment: Thanks Ratan, anything from your experience? what kind of applications are being developed that use these APIs?

Comment: Ron.. check karthikselva ans.. In my experience. I have requirement when we have to integrate salesforce and JIRA system both are completely different. In this type of scenario we use  API (In my case we used Rest API).. One more from my experience. We had a requirement when we have to sync data from two different salesforce orgs that time we used SOAP API to make callout to sync the data.. Basically I can when we need play with two different system then API comes into the picture..

Comment: Yes. These applications could be written in any language and not necessary built on Force.com, correct?

Comment: Yes.. Correct we can connect two different system..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36310/discussion-between-ron-daniel-and-ratan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Salesforce API's enables you to access data beyond the Salesforce environment.

**Overview:**

- Currently I am assuming you do most of your development within Salesforce and customization in Apex.
- If there are two different systems with entirely different technology and tool stack then API is the key which allows you to integrate them both
- I had zero knowledge on Apex and Salesforce environment when I started, and had to retrieve data from it since the key data is lying there.

**Scenario:**

```
     RoR App <- Salesforce
```

- I had a scenario where I need to pull Revenue data from different systems and display a chart on my Ruby on Rails application
- Customer where using different applications simultaneously and there is no central place for revenue data
- I used REST API to query Salesforce data (Salesforce had the best documentation than other systems so it was piece of cake to retrieve the data)
- So why REST and why not BULK API is a really broad discussions, where you need to consider synchronous vs asynchronous, volume of data, implementation complexity, but I hope you got the high level idea atleast.

When choosing between API's you need to consider different dimensions of your integration and here @Ratan's [reference](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm) will come in handy for you.

**Summary:**

- Decide what data you want (it might range from Meta of objects to Analytics data) through API
- If you have multiple options (in Salesforce surely there are multiple ways to achieve the same thing) decide which works best for your integration by laying out the dimensions

**Note:**

Unless there is a need to use API don't go for it, since API calls cost you both in time (I mean the response time) and money (API limits)